# Add CSS to WooCommerce product pages only if product is not on sale

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, price

I need to add some CSS to hide some elements/classes on the page if the product is NOT on sale.

From another function I have, I am assuming I can check if `$args['meta_key'] = '_sale_price';` is blank and if it then adds the CSS.

How can I use this in my functions.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_action( 'wp', 'add_cssif_product_not_onsale' );

function add_cssif_product_not_onsale() {

    if ( is_product() ) {
        global $post;
        $product = wc_get_product( $post );
        if ( !$product->is_on_sale() )
            echo "<style>body{display:none}</style>";
    }
}
```